# Obfuscar for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac, obfuscar

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app using Visual Studio for Mac (Community Edition). I'm able to decompile the source code of the Android application using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)

In order to obfuscate the source code, I used [Obfuscar](https://docs.obfuscar.com/) and followed the steps in https://docs.obfuscar.com/tutorials/xamarin.html

- Below is the Xamarin.Android project structure

[image]

- Below is the configuration in `obfuscar.xml`

```
    <Obfuscator>
        <Var name="RenameProperties" value="true" />
        <Var name="RenameEvents" value="true" />
        <Var name="RenameFields" value="true" />
        <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
        <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />
        <Var name="HideStrings" value="true" />
        <Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="true" />
        <Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="true" />
        <Var name="InPath" value="./bin/Release" />
        <Var name="OutPath" value="./bin/Release/Obfuscator_Output" />
        <Module file="$(InPath)/Sample.dll" />
    </Obfuscator>
```

- Below changes are done in the Android.csproj

[image]

When the project is built in the `Release` mode, Archived, and Decompiled, the source code is still visible in plain text using ILSpy.

[image]

I need help in configuring Obfuscator correctly for the Xamarin.Forms project

Comment: Does obfuscation log file mapping.txt is generated? I have not used Obfuscar but similar tool I have used. That tool will generate obfuscation report. If report generated then only obfuscation is success. So, obfuscar also may follow similar approach. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything worked fine with the below Obfuscar configuration

```
<Obfuscator>
    <Var name="RenameProperties" value="true" />
    <Var name="RenameEvents" value="true" />
    <Var name="RenameFields" value="true" />
    <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
    <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />
    <Var name="HideStrings" value="true" />
    <Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="true" />
    <Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="true" />
    <Var name="InPath" value="/Users/sahil.khanna/path_to_xamarin_project/Sample.Android/bin/Release" />
    <Var name="OutPath" value="$(InPath)/Obfuscator_Output" />
    <Module file="$(InPath)/Sample.dll" />
</Obfuscator>
```

Strangely, `InPath` and `OutPath` worked with an absolute path instead of a relative path on a Mac. The only changes I did were in the `InPath` and `OutPath` to make it work.