# Xamarin.Android app crashes after running Obfuscar (Visual Studio for Mac)

Tags: xamarin.android, obfuscation, obfuscar, android-obfuscation

I've got a basic Xamarin.Android project setup with Obfuscar configured

The obfuscar.xml:

```
<Obfuscator>
    <Var name="RenameProperties" value="true" />
    <Var name="RenameEvents" value="true" />
    <Var name="RenameFields" value="true" />
    <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
    <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />
    <Var name="HideStrings" value="true" />
    <Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="true" />
    <Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="true" />
    <Var name="InPath" value="/Users/user1/Documents/dev/project/src/MyProject.Android/bin/Debug" />
    <Var name="OutPath" value="$(InPath)/Obfuscator_Output" />
    <Module file="$(InPath)/MyProject.dll" />
</Obfuscator>
```

And in the csproj file (I targeted Debug configuration to debug this issue):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
      <Message Importance="High" Text="Obfuscar task has been called." />
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MonoAndroidIntermediateAssetsDir)" Command="$(Obfuscar) $(ProjectDir)obfuscar.xml" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)MyProject.dll" DestinationFolder="$(MonoAndroidIntermediateAssetsDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Obfuscation does seem to work.. mapping.txt is generated and I see the following in the build logs:

```
Target AfterBuild:
    Obfuscar task has been called.
    mono /Users/user1/.nuget/packages/obfuscar/2.2.33/build/../tools/Obfuscar.Console.exe /Users/user1/Documents/dev/project/src/MyProject.Android/obfuscar.xml
    Note that Rollbar API is enabled by default to collect crashes. If you want to opt out, please run with -s switch
    Loading project /Users/user1/Documents/dev/project/src/MyProject.Android/obfuscar.xml...Processing assembly: Solo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    Loading assemblies...Extra framework folders: Done.
    Hiding strings...
    Renaming:  fields...Parameters...Properties...Events...Methods...Types...Done.
    Saving assemblies...Done.
    Writing log file...Done.
    Completed, 10.76 secs.
    Copying file from "/Users/user1/Documents/dev/project/src/MyProject.Android/bin/Debug/MyProject.dll" to "/Users/user1/Documents/dev/project/src/MyProject.Android/obj/Debug/android/assets/MyProject.dll".
```

However, when the app does run, it immediately crashes upon startup with:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Can this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1199208-6203-4237-8cf2-5ee3a0e80416/when-in-the-build-process-should-i-obfuscate-and-where-do-i-copy-the-results?forum=xamarinandroid) provide some help for you? Or you can check the [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349309/obfuscar-for-xamarin-forms) which used Obfuscar on visual studio for mac.

Comment: I saw the first link before I posted this — obfuscation works as intended but I’m trying to figure out the crash. The 2nd link is related to confuserEx not obfuscar (saw that before I posted as well).

Comment: So had the Exception been resolved now? According to the first link, the obfuscar is too old and the error isn't mentioned in it's document either.